# Android layout text on new line

Tags: java, android

Now i have such xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bank_e"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bank_e"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bank_e_n"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bank_e_n"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:typeface="serif" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/naspunkt_e"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/nas_punkt_e"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nas_punkt_e_n"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bank_e_n" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adres_obmennika_e"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/adres_obmennika_e"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adress_obm_e_n"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bank_e_n"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shirota_e"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/shirota_e" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shirota_e_n"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bank_e_n" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dolgota_e"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dolgota_e" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dolgota_e_n"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bank_e_n" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

And my activity looks so:

[image]

But i need to change it to such look:

[image]

What i need to change? I'm new to android... In css (web) it's much easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bank_e"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bank_e"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bank_e_n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bank_e_n"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />
```

Notice the extra `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bank_e"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bank_e"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bank_e_n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bank_e_n"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/naspunkt_e"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nas_punkt_e"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nas_punkt_e_n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bank_e_n" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adres_obmennika_e"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/adres_obmennika_e"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adress_obm_e_n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bank_e_n"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shirota_e"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/shirota_e" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shirota_e_n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bank_e_n" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dolgota_e"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dolgota_e" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dolgota_e_n"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bank_e_n" />
```

This will put every child item below the last one.